# Google Maps JavaScript API: Map Type Control, disable checkbox "labels"

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

In Google Map API, we have the Map Type Control in the top right corner, So we can choose between Map|Satellite.

My problem is when I click on "Satellite", a checkbox appears with input "labels", and when I click on "Map", a checkbox appears with input "terrain".

I want to disable checkbox control and fix Satellite with labels checked without showing the checkbox when clicking on, and the same thing with Map Type I want to have "terrain" unchecked without showing the checkbox on clicking.

Comment: Would you mind providing a [JSBIN](http://www.jsbin.com) or [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) for context? It's best to provide a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when asking people to review the intricacies of your code. It's part of the ["How do I ask a good question?" documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

To remove those checkboxes, and set the buttons to the options you want, create a custom `mapTypeIds` property for the map, removing 'terrain' and 'satellite' (so the only typeIds are 'roadmap' and 'hybrid'):

```
mapTypeControlOptions: {
  mapTypeIds: ['roadmap', 'hybrid']
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/2q6g49aq/) (modified from [this example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-options) in the documentation)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {
      lat: -33,
      lng: 151
    },
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      mapTypeIds: ['roadmap', 'hybrid']
    }
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk">
</script>
```